# Confuse about self attribute and declaration in Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I am currently trying to understand some basic concepts of Python.

Code Sample:

```
class BorgSingleton:
    _shared_borg_state = {}
    test = "toto"

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self._shared_borg_state
        print("borg created")
        print(self.test)
    
class Point(BorgSingleton) :

    def __init__(self, lat, long):
        self.latitude = lat
        self.longitude = long
        super().__init__()
        print (self.latitude)
    
    def g(self) :
        return BorgSingleton.test +" " +str(self.latitude) + " " + str(self.longitude)
    
    
def main():
    point_1 = Point(5,2)
    point_2 = Point(3,3)
    print(point_1.g())
    print(point_2.g())
    point_1.test = "tata"
    print(point_1.g())
    print(point_2.g())

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

Code Execution:

> borg created
> toto
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "file1.py", line 32, in 
> main()
> File "file1.py", line 23, in main
> point_1 = Point(5,2)
> File "file1.py", line 16, in **init**
> print (self.latitude)
> AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'latitude'

I'm sure I'm making a basic mistake in python, but am not sure why my instance `point_1` of the class `Point` doesn't have the `latitude` attribute.

I read about Inheritance and Borg conception, but something is missing. I have also tried the -tt option for indentation mistake.

Comment: Just move the `super()` call to be the first line in `_init__()`

Comment: Your base class is replacing `__dict__`, which is the attributes of the object, with the empty `_shared_borg_state` therefore discarding the existing `__dict__` state of the object which contains attributes `latitude` and `longitude` defined at the beginning of `Point.__init__`.

Answer (score 2):

The code you've wrote should've worked if `self.__dict__` had not been overridden in the parent `BorgSingleton` class.

In Python, it is not a good practice to override magic methods (ones that start and end with double-unders) unless you know what you're doing.

To generalize what happened, lets see the below two classes:

```
class Parent:
    some_attribute = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self.some_attribute


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, arg_1, arg_2):
        self.arg_1 = arg_1
        self.arg_2 = arg_2
        # at this point, an instance of class Child has arg_1 and arg_2
        # attributes, and self.__dict__ stores corresponding values
        super().__init__()
        # in the Parent class, self.__dict__ is overridden to an empty dict 
        # which makes arg_1 and arg_2 arguments unaccessible from the 
        # instance after a super call


test_instance = Child(1, 2)
```

**Update based on additional question, asked in comments:**

In order to change an attribute of several model instances, we have to iterate over a collection of these instances, setting the desired value to the corresponding attribute.

Having partially refactored your code, running this code:

```
class BorgSingleton:
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Assigning default value to attribute.
        """
        self.test = 'toto'


class Point(BorgSingleton):
    def __init__(self, lat, long):
        self.latitude = lat
        self.longitude = long
        super().__init__()

    def g(self):
        return f'{self.test} {self.latitude} {self.longitude}'


class Points:
    def __init__(self, collection_of_points):
        """
        Before we instantiate Points, check that collection_of_points is a list
        and all elements of a list are the instances of Point class.
        """
        if (isinstance(collection_of_points, list) and
                all([isinstance(x, Point) for x in collection_of_points])):
            self.points = collection_of_points
        else:
            raise ValueError

    def assign_new_value_for_test_attribute(self, value):
        """
        Iterate over all Point class instances, stored in self.points,
        and change values of test attribute.
        """
        [setattr(x, 'test', value) for x in self.points]


def main():
    point_1 = Point(5, 2)
    point_2 = Point(3, 3)
    print(point_1.g())
    print(point_2.g())
    points = Points([point_1, point_2])
    points.assign_new_value_for_test_attribute('tata')
    print(point_1.g())
    print(point_2.g())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

results in this:

```
toto 5 2
toto 3 3
tata 5 2
tata 3 3
```

Here, we create an instance of `Points` class, which stores `point_1` and `point_2` instances in `Points.points` attribute. Then, calling `Points.assign_new_value_for_test_attribute` method, [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is used to update `test` attribute of `point_1` and `point_2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i understand better the mechanics. I was not aware about the __dict__. Thank you.
Something more, when i did `point_1.test = "tata"` i don't want to just modify the test for point1 instance, i would like to modify the test for all the child of the borg class. I thought it was the way a borg should work. I want `test` to be a common variable for all these child.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put `super().__init__()` as first instruction in `__init__()` method of class Point:

```
class BorgSingleton:
    _shared_borg_state = {}
    test = "toto"

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self._shared_borg_state
        print("borg created")
        print(self.test)


class Point(BorgSingleton):

    def __init__(self, lat, long):
        super().__init__()
        self.latitude = lat
        self.longitude = long
        #super().__init__()
        print(self.latitude)

    def g(self):
        return BorgSingleton.test + " " + str(self.latitude) + " " + str(self.longitude)


def main():
    point_1 = Point(5, 2)
    point_2 = Point(3, 3)
    print(point_1.g())
    print(point_2.g())
    point_1.test = "tata"
    print(point_1.g())
    print(point_2.g())


if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

With this modification the attributes `latitute` and `longitude` will be present in the instances of the class `Point`.